Production Cluster performance - vector database
My goal is to deploy either a ChromaDB, Elasticsearch or Milvus vector databases for production.
Looking for advice from the community about their experience about production deployment with these technologies interms of :

reliability
scalability
security

EDIT 1 Additionally:

it is also mentioned here on Llamaindex page that ChromaDB does not directly implement hybrid search. What are some of the implementation out there for such databases that lack this capability? Is it only a post processsing or are there ways to scale this process for a faster result?

I notice that "ASYNCHRONOUS" is one of the categories for evaluating a database. For vector database, how important is that?


I thank you all for the advice in advance !
